# property private set crashes unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, properties, coroutine

I have a custom class that gets some data from the web.
When I get this data I want to set it to the value of a property but when I do this unity crashes. The commented line generates the crash without this line everything works fine. See my code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class GetDB
{
    private readonly Main m;
    private readonly string Url;

    public string DBData { 
        get
        {
            if(DBData == null)
                return null;
            else
                return DBData;
        } 
        private set
        {
            DBData = value;
        } 
    }

    public GetDB(Main m, string url)
    {
        this.m = m;
        this.Url = url;
    }

    public void GetServerData(){
        m.StartCoroutine(GetText(Url, (result) =>{
            this.DBData = result; //THIS LINE CRASHES UNITY
            Debug.Log(result);
        }));
    }

    IEnumerator GetText(string url, Action<string> result) {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else {
            if (result != null)
                result(www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
}
```

How would I go about fixing this, and what exactly is happening here?

If anything is unclear let me know so I can clarify.

Comment: `DBData = value;` that's your problem. You have to use a backing field.

Comment: i am quite new to c# in general so what exactly is a backing field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties act as accessors for variables. What is happening in your case is basically an endless loop - whenever somebody tries to get the value of your property, it keeps returning the property itself. Instead, you want a backing field _dbData:

```
private string _dbData;
public string DBData 
{ 
    get
    {
        return _dbData;
    } 
    private set
    {
        _dbData = value;
    } 
}
```

Now your property controls the accesss to this field.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use a backing field for the property:

```
string _dbData;

public string DBData
{
    get
    {
        if(_dbData == null)
            return null;
        else
            return _dbData;
    }
    private set
    {
        _dbData= value;
    }
}
```

A property is just syntactic sugar for a getter and setter methods. So you can rewrite your property like:

```
public string GetDBData()
{
    if(_dbData == null)
        return null;
    else
        return _dbData;
}

public void SetDBData(string value)
{
    _dbData = value;
}
```

The way you have implemented the property:

```
public void SetDBData(string value)
{
    // you will never get out of here
    SetDBData(value);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to add to your answer some explanation about why his code didn't work, like the way he did it provided an infinite recursion, then a stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Your accessor can be really simplified.

Doing :

```
get
{
    if(DBData == null)
        return null;
    else
        return DBData;
}
```

Will provide exactly the same result than doing :

```
get
{
    return DBData; //if DBData is null, it will return null
}
```

So, you can write your accessor that way :

```
public string DBData 
{ 
    get;
    private set;
}
```